# Cross Browser Import for HTML Templates

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I have checked and there are "similar" questions here but I want to rule out Google's polyfil for WebComponents and also time has moved on since the majority of the 2015 discussions and, most importantly, Javascript Modules appear to have ruled themselves out of providing "import" template functionality. (Sticking to importing VARs, Functions, and Objects from other modules only)

So to my question: -

"What is the suggested/best cross-browser solution for importing/including HTML Templates?"

I see nothing wrong, functionality wise, with Chrome's `<LINK TYPE="IMPORT">` but unfortunately Safari, Firefox, and Edge seemed to have ruled it out :-(

So what's next best?

```
XHR2 responseType="document?

XHR type="text/html" 
document.createElement("template").innerHTML = responseText
document.headd.appendChild(newTemplate);
?

<script id="storeStringsHere></script> ?
```

Anything else?

ShadowDOM V1.0, Templates, Modules, and even Custom Components look to be all making the cut. (Which is great!) but with HTML Imports being black-balled we/I need an alternative cross-browser solution. Please help.

Why is LINK good for CSS but not for Templates?

Comment: Please define a bit more what you actually want out of this. You can *link* to a file in some way, okay, fine, but then how is it going to be used after that? HTML has no native way (yet) to put that template anywhere in the main document.

Comment: @deceze It just works: - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/ but IMPORT does not enjoy such cross-browser support nor does it look like it ever will. For those who agree with me that HTML Templates are here to stay please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no native solution, use HTML Imports (native or polyfilled) is a solution as good as any other one (`XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch`, other JS library) to import templates as HTML files.

Anyways [HTML Imports polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports), like any other Module Loader JS library, uses `XMLHttpRequest` under the wood. So don't consider it as a polyfill but as just yet another JS module loader.

Alternately you can implement your own Module Loader with `XMLHttpRequest` (or `fetch`). It's just a few lines of codes.

Comment: IMHO, looking at the polyfill code, it is bloatware to crack a nut :-( XHR is just a tiny part of extensive mitigation capabilities. I guess I will go the XHR but was wondering what was the "best" encapulation option for am ES6 Module with Shadow DOM and local scoped CSS?

Comment: ES6 Modules only deals with JS files so the only option here is to use full JS custom elements with templates defined as template literals.

Comment: I agree that Modules offer no new template import functionality which leaves me at a loss to explain the recalcitrance of Safari, Firefox, and Edge in supporting LINK IMPORT. They seem unanimous in their disdain for Chrome's proposed feature but no one explains why or what the alternative is :-(

Comment: @McMurphy I agree with you